Movie with cyborg or robot shooting bullets from his head
This movie maybe from USA, Canada or some other country but it definitely had american accents in the movie. I saw it in the late 90s.
Here are some scenes I remember:
In this clip a robot or cyborg shoots bullets from his head. This is how the scene appears. First a man walks by in a visually blue area then in the cinematography, the camera zooms towards the robot's head, then his forehead opens and then a canon or rocket type gun shoots from its forehead.

Take a look at Nemesis
The sci-fi actioner starred foreigners aplenty, so that might account for the "other"country" element of your description and, of course, this charming fellow. 

